# Validation Rule Best Practise

Tags: validation-rule, bestpractice

I would like to know the best practice while creating a validation rule in Salesforce. Whether we need to split it down as much as we can(so that it's easier to understand and could give specific error message) or we need to merge as much possible(don't know whether less validations means more efficiency)

In my scenario, I want to restrict status change of Case in 2 scenario. Personally I would prefer to add them separetely but the object is already filled with around 20 validations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat subjective, so opinion based, but my recommendation is to have dedicated validation rules for specific checks.

It means the user can be guided better, and you can have the validation associated with a field.

In terms of best practice, where possible have the validation only apply to initial setting and subsequent changes of the values of relevant fields. Doing this means automations that update unrelated fields are not prevented from functioning if the object is already "invalid" (e.g. because validation was added after records were created).

Comment: I wouldn't say it's opinion-based, really. User experience should come before any sense of "optimization" at this level. The time spent validating records doesn't count against CPU time, heap limit, etc, so there's no real incentive to optimize to that level.